# Umbraco Content Tabs are Blank

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco

I have an Umbraco 4.7.1.1 site that has mysteriously lost its Content and Properties data for one specific data type. The data type is complete in Settings / Document Types, but when viewed in the Content Tree, there is no content. See link for screenshot: [Screenshot](http://test.vintagenine.com/umbraco.gif)

The data was uploaded using CMS Import and has been live on the site for months now but just now starting showing this issue. I've tried republishing the content and cycling the App Pool, to no success. Ideas?

Comment: What datatypes do you have on the document type? My guess is that one of the data types has some faulty javascript that is erroring out. Check the console for any errors to rule that out.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check whether the `<compilation>` tag in your web.config has the debug attribute set to "true"? The Umbraco back-office has a number of issues that only become present when the Client Dependency CSS & Javascript caching & minifying library included with Umbraco is activated, which happens when debug mode is set to "false" (or is not present). Setting it to true means that the back-office CSS & JS is not minified, and may solve your problem.